# How do I post a collection to a controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a collection of form checkboxes that I am using JQuery to asynchronously post the checkbox values to a controller. What is the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is about model binding, Phil Haack posted an article that may be useful.

- Model Binding To A List: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Comment: Just to save time to read phill's long post - If question is about model binding then use hidden text box for checkbox id.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using JSON then populating a class or something off of that inside the object.

Comment: Can I post JSon TO a controller (not returned from).

Answer (score 0):

[Malsup's ajax form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) is, I think, the easiest way to do this. Your action treats it like any other form post.